# Rails:Send mail using mailer when controller finishes its execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, mailer

I am using a **button** for **report abuse**, clicking on which **ajax call** goes to **controller** and after **inserting** post as **abused** in **database** it is returning success. On successful response it is displaying on UI topic as abused.
Now i want to **send mails** to admin about this. I have **integrated mailer in controller**, i.e. on success mailer code executes and mails are send to admin.

Now problem is that **sending mails take too much time**, so my **ajax response time** also **increases**. What I want is that **mailer code** should **execute after controller** sends its **response**, so that response time should decrease.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use resque mailer - https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer/

More info: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/resque_mailer

It's pretty easy to set up.

More info:
http://blog.zerosum.org/2010/1/9/resque-mailer.html
http://www.scottw.com/simple-resque-mail-queue
http://ku1ik.com/2011/04/05/resque-mailer-says-put-your-emails-to-background.html

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this is to create a Thread to handle the email. Simply do:

```
Thread.new do
  SomeMailer.some_method.deliver
end
```

Your controller action will continue and finish the Ajax response while the thread is separately handled.  Keep in mind that if your mailer has extensive processing, then it will likely fail (and it won't any log errors as Threads are not logged) if still processing beyond the time to complete the main controller action. This will only happen in development as the classes are un-instantiated upon completion. To fix this, just change this in your development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

You can also use a background job process, but for lighter loads, Threads work great and are easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using delayed_job?

Comment: Almost finished writing the same :)